# ASP.NET - Infinite loop when using server.execute

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, infinite-loop, textwriter

When using `server.execute` to capture the html of the current page the following code gets stuck in an infinite loop.

**On Debug**

`Server.Execute` causes the button click event to fire each time. But why?

It appears that `preserveForm = true` is maintaining the click event within the form but I need this to maintain my querystrings.

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
  test()
End Sub

Protected Sub test()
  Dim writer As TextWriter = New StringWriter()
  Server.Execute("ThisPage", writer, True)
End Sub
```

I am aware I can do some kind or variable flag to check for the return of the loop but I want to know:

- Is this correct behaviour?
- Is so, why?
- Clean method to avoid the loop.
- Recommended alternate methods to capture entire page html.

Comment: What happens if you set preserveForm to false?

Comment: Can't you just pass the current query strings along as part of the `path` parameter?

Comment: @CalC Yes that's what I am going to do. You should post an answer to the fact that preserveForm maintains active events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the MSDN page for the [HttpServerUtility.Execute Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8e2dw5s(v=vs.110).aspx), the `preserveFrom` parameter of this method has the following defined behaviour:

> *preserveForm*
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> **true** to preserve the QueryString and
>   Form collections; **false** to clear the QueryString and Form collections.

The Form collection will include state data for the Controls on the page. As such, this could lead to an infinite loop if Execute() is performed as part of an event.